# Windows 10 Google OAuth. Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: . Path '', line 0, position 0

Tags: c#, windows-10, google-api-dotnet-client, google-authentication

I'm using Google Auth .net Api for client side authentication

```
var clientSecrets = new Uri(SettingsViewModel.GoogleClientSecretsUri);
this.UserCredential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    clientSecrets,
    this.Scopes,
    "user",
    CancellationToken.None
    );
```

After Google login webcontrol calls back the client it throws:

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: . Path '', line
>   0, position 0.

Any suggestion how I can fix this?

Comment: I'll make a guess: Google returns an error page with html content, not json.

Comment: Would it happen even after showing the right consent page?

Comment: Download [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and watch your network traffic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a chance to look more into this, 
The access_token response from google is GZip encoded and their API does not decode it before constructing the json response. 
As a work around until the lib files are fixed you can use the solution here with little modification 
http://blog.kulman.sk/implementing-google-login-in-universal-apps/
...

```
        var responseStream = new GZipStream(await auth.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(), CompressionMode.Decompress);
        var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        var data = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Debug.WriteLine(data);
```

...